# How to draw a diamond in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm doing a project right now, and I need help making diamonds appear in GUI for Java. I can make other shapes appear, but how do you do diamonds? Any help would be appreciated.

// and I'm looking to do this without triangles, but if there's no other way, please assist me with that.

Comment: Please define "making diamonds appear in GUI". What GUI library? What image exactly are you trying to achieve? What code do you have so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Sorry, but this seems a very incomplete question as currently written. Please help fix this.

Comment: Again, please clarify your question so that it is in fact answerable, else it risks being closed. Voting to close question as unclear unless it can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "diamond" you mean something like this <> (obviously with connected edges), you can simply draw it with lines. Assuming, the graphics library allows you to draw lines.

If you were to draw a diamond given its center point 'c', you can achieve this as follows:

Line 1: `from c.x, c.y - diamond.height/2 to c.x - diamond.width/2, c.y`

Line 2: `from c.x, c.y - diamond.height/2 to c.x + diamond.width/2, c.y`

Line 3: `from c.x - diamond.width/2, c.y to c.x, c.y + diamond.height/2`

Line 4: `from c.x + diamond.width/2, c.y to c.x, c.y + diamond.height/2`

Comment: from my amateur perspective I think he wants to draw a shape something like pyramid through looping , like drawing using `*`, or he wants to draw a shape to a frame, but who knows, and plus one for the explanation